# Have any countries managed to reduce the total number of words in their laws?

Tags: law, bureaucracy

As an example, the [US tax code grew](https://taxfoundation.org/federal-tax-laws-and-regulations-are-now-over-10-million-words-long/) from 1.4m words in 1955 to 10m words in 2015:

[image]

Are there countries that managed to reduce the total number of words in their legal code? To avoid an overly broad answer, I'm only interested in examples of this happening over the past 50 years.

Comment: A tax code is a very specialized set of regulations, which is often impacted by special rules to grant special favors to special groups (invest in industry X to get Y% off for example).  Simplifying it would mean paring it back down to a simpler form, minus all the tax avoidance loopholes.  That would probably get some pushback from special interest groups (tax specialists, millionaires).  But economists would typically see it as a net positive.

Comment: Paring back general laws and regulations however means giving up govt. control on certain activities. That's not necessarily the same thing.  So which are you most interested in?  General laws or tax laws?

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica general laws, I've used the tax code as an example because I could find a nice graph for it

Comment: You want to look for Code of Federal Regulations apparently then.  https://cei.org/blog/new-data-code-of-federal-regulations-expanding-faster-pace-under-obama/

Comment: Isn't it better for SE.History (or even SE.Law?), even if only the 'past 50 tears'? (A more 'political' question would be 'why is it not (generally) happening?')

Comment: There may be a problem with the definition of what constitutes the 'legal code'. The process of amending regulations does not necessarily remove anything. It may be implemented by adding appendices in what programmers like me would call a patch-like syntax, e.g. "as of day X, the first three words in paragraph Y are replaced by Z". Does this increase the length of the law? The new effective consolidated version may occasionally be unclear until tested in court.

Comment: Why would they want to do so?

Comment: Simplifying it would mean paring it back down to a simpler form, minus all the tax avoidance loopholes." Fewer words often means more ambiguity not fewer loopholes. Often it adds loopholes to reduce words.

Comment: @ohwilleke No, fewer loopholes means fewer special cases.  No "6% rebate for supporting Canadian film making industry", for example, just the "usual rate of capital/corporate gains taxes", whether or not you are investing in Canadian film, renewables, hydroponic farming, etc...  Easy to streamline here:  get rid of the special cases, lower the overall tax rate if needed to keep revenue neutrality and stop having so many pet projects put in place by lawmakers.  That's why I specifically asked if tax code was really what OP was after, because I agree general laws and regulation are hard trimming

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica if someone at least trimmed their tax code, I'd accept that as an answer!

Comment: K, I'll take a look around if there has *ever* been a sighting of this mythical beast.

Comment: Estonia seems to have simplified their tax code repetitively, in 1994 and 2000.  But the number of pages is not discussed and most of the coverage is centered on the adoption of a flat tax.  i.e. between the lines, you can *guess* that there were less pages after than before, but that is **not** reported as such and not apparent.  No doubt an Estonian tax specialist would be able to ascertain it.  https://kluwerlawonline.com/journalarticle/Intertax/49.10/TAXI2021081.

Comment: Also of interest (UK), because it specifically talks about length https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/603470/OTS_length_of_legislation_paper_published_Apr12.pdf  And I wonder if some of Ireland's tax reforms to attract FDI did not result in shortening.